# Merge the uiview from both sides to the centre of the view with animation

Tags: ios, animation, core-animation

I am developing an iphone application.can anybody tell me how to slide a view from both ends and merge at the centre with animation.Please help me with a solution.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know there are no default possibilites. But you can maybe tile your image in two halfs and use core-animation to slide on half from the right side and one half from the left side in?

Comment: That's exactly what I've done in the past, except I make a "snapshot" of the view using CAReplicatorLayer,hide the original view with a masking layer , put half in each of two layers, animate them in and then in the animation completion block, unhide the real view by removing the masking layer and destroying the replicated layers.  I hope that made sense.